# WCSession Delegate | Is it necessary to call reply handler synchronously?

Tags: swift, watchkit, wcsession

Is it necessary to call replyHandler before delegate function returns? I need to make few Web Service API calls before I can reply, is following implementation correct?

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         //Following function makes couple of API calls inside 
         //UIBackgroundTask and replies when 
         //background task time expires 
         //or response from API is received.
         self.handleMessage(message, replyHandler: replyHandler)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's fine to grab a copy of the block and call it later, though if you wait too long and your app is running in the background you may get suspended.